# If $A \approx \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is some ordinal, then $A$ is well-orderable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations, cardinals, ordinals

I would like to prove the following claim:

> If $A \approx \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is some ordinal, then $A$ is well-orderable

I have no experience with a proof like this, but I imagine it amounts to constructing a **set of ordered pairs** $R'$ equipped with the following properties:

1. $R' \subseteq A \times A$
2. $R'$ is *irreflexive* $\iff$ $\forall x \in A [x\not R' x$]
3. $R'$ is *transitive* $\iff$ $\forall x,y,z \in A [xR'y \land yR'z \rightarrow xR'z]$
4. $R'$ satisfies *trichotomy* $\iff$ $\forall x,y \in A [xR'y \lor yR'x \lor x=y]$
5. $R'$ is *well-founded* $\iff$ $\forall X \big[X \neq \emptyset \land X \subseteq A \rightarrow \exists y \big(y \in X \land \neg \exists z (z \in X \land z R' y)\big)\big]$

The above definitions are all taken from my book: *The Foundations of Mathematics*: By Kenneth Kunen

---

To start, assume that $A \approx \alpha$ $\iff$ there exists a bijection $f$ such that $f: \alpha \xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{1-1}A$

Additionally, because $\alpha$ is an ordinal, it is well ordered by $\in$.

(*Not sure I can do this*) In particular then, imagine an $\in_\alpha \subseteq \alpha \times \alpha \quad$ i.e. $\in_\alpha$ is the set of ordered pairs that well-orders $\alpha$.

Consider the following function with its accompanying mapping rule:

$g: \in_\alpha \to A \times A$

where $\forall \langle \alpha_0, \alpha_1 \rangle \in \ \in_\alpha: \quad$ $g\big(\langle\alpha_0,\alpha_1 \rangle \big)= \langle f(\alpha_0),f(\alpha_1) \rangle$

My belief is that $g[\in_\alpha]$ is effectively the $R'$ that I initially aimed to construct...i.e. $\quad R' = \text{ran}(g)$

It seems like properties 2-5 can all be proven by contradiction:

E.G.

Assume $R'$ is ***not*** irreflexive. Therefore, $\exists x \in A [xR'x]$. Let $\langle x,x \rangle \in R' \iff \langle x,x \rangle \in \text{ran}(g)$

By definition of $g$, this means that $\exists \delta \big( \delta \in \alpha \land f(\delta)=x \land g( \langle \delta, \delta \rangle) =\langle x,x \rangle\big)$.

But this implies that $\langle \delta, \delta \rangle \in \ \in_\alpha$, which is a contradiction because $\in_\alpha$ is irreflexive.

---

Does this general strategy work? Cheers~

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. Given the bijection $f:A\to\alpha$, consider the order on $A$ given by $x<y$ iff $f(x)<f(y)$. Proving that this works is trivial. (If you want a more rigorous construction of this order, just take the order on the ordinal alpha, construct a function $f^*:\alpha\times\alpha\to A\times A$ given by $f^*(x,y)=(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))$, and consider the image of the restriction of $f^*$ to the order on $\alpha$).

Comment: @DonThousand thank you for the input! When you say "consider the order on A given by $x \lt y \iff f(x) \lt f(y)$", are you really defining a "$\lt ^*$"? (if you get what I mean). That is to say, If $f(x) \lt f(y)$ then $\langle x,y \rangle \in \lt^*$?. Ahhh, your edit makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @S.Cramer: Yes, he’s defining an order $\prec$ on $A$ by $a\prec b$ iff $f(a)<f(b)$ in $\alpha$. This automatically makes $f$ an order-isomorphism and hence makes $\prec$ a (strict) well-order.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Perfect. One question, though: in my book, an isomorphism is described as a bijection $F: A \xrightarrow[\text{onto}]{1-1} B$ and $\forall x,y \in A [x \lt y \leftrightarrow F(x) \lhd F(y)]$. The author adds that "...this is a special case of the general notion of isomorphism between arbitrary algebraic structures...". No where is it explicitly stated that isomorphisms preserve order. Thus, it appears the onus is on me to prove (just once) that the author's isomorphism definition preserves order. How do I do this in general (i.e. not just for a strict well-order).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott informally, I can see that the statement $\forall x,y \in A [ x \lt y \leftrightarrow F(x) \lhd F(y) ]$ basically amounts to saying the sets $\lt$ and $\lhd$ "are the same but with different aliases"...however, that does seem pretty...informal. Is it effectively a symmetry argument I am making? i.e. Whatever proof method I used to demonstrate that $\lt$ was transitive/irreflexive/reflexive/symmetric/well-founded/etc necessarily is the same argument for $\lhd$ but with changes in symbols from $x$ to $F(x)$?

Comment: @S.Cramer: There’s really nothing to prove: that’s the **definition** of preserving order.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'll try to ask this differently...as I think sometimes my English language/word choice interferes with established mathematical terms. Suppose I have two relations $\prec$ and $\lhd$, a surjective function $F: A \to B$ and I know: $\prec \text{ is irreflexive on } A \land \forall x,y \in A [ x \prec y \leftrightarrow F(x) \lhd F(y) ]$. I want to prove that $\lhd \text{ is irreflexive on } B$...i.e. I want to show that $\forall b \in B [ b \not \lhd b]$. It appears as though this claim would require a proof by contradiction, right?

Comment: I guess my point is that the definition $\forall x,y \in A [ x \prec y \leftrightarrow F(x) \lhd F(y) ]$ is not sufficient to demonstrate that $\lhd$ must also be irreflexive. I have to prove that this definition PRODUCES the desired result.

Comment: @S.Cramer: Your hypothesis says that $F$ is an isomorphism with respect to the relations, so any proper possessed by one is automatically possessed by the other. In particular, if $\prec$ is irreflexive, then $x\not\prec x$ for all $x\in A$, which immediately tells you that $y\not\lhd y$ for all $y\in B$, since $F$ is a bijection.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm an idiot. Hah. I was not interpreting the biconditional correctly. "Both false or both true". Right, right. Thank you for the patience. Cheers~

Comment: @S.Cramer: No problem; you’re welcome!